# Consecutive Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Assume that the sequence of Fibonacci numbers begins with 2 instead of 1,i.e., $$F_1=2,F_2=3,F_3=5,...$$

Let $F_n$ denote the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number. I have to prove these two claims.

**Claim 1:** $F^2_{n+1} = 1 \mod F_n$.

**Claim 2:** $F^2_{n} = -1 \mod F_{n+1}$.

I do not know where to go with this. I have probably missed something that obvious in the "induction" step of proof. But I cannot realize it.

Any help or suggestion?

Comment: Is above improvement sufficient to clarify question?

Comment: That's fine, I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $F_n^2-F_{n+1}F_{n-1}=(-1)^{n+1}$ which you should be able to prove, and then use.

With these kind of things it is sometimes worth looking for a stronger statement which is more amenable to the induction you are trying to use.

Comment: By taking $\mod F_{n+1}$ of two sides in the Cassini's identity, we get $F^2_n = (-1)^{n+1} \mod F_{n+1}$. But there is a sign ambiguity depending on $n$. I claimed stronger than that one.

Comment: @ToposLogos $3^2\equiv -1 \bmod 5, 5^2\equiv 1 \bmod 8$ and the signs alternate. Likewise $5^2\equiv 1 \bmod 3, 8^2\equiv -1 \bmod 5$ and the signs alternate for that one too. You can't prove that the sign is constant, because it isn't.